# can you have too many user controls

Tags: c#, winforms

I am putting together a winforms project and I was thinking of using user controls with one form. For example, having a user control for customer lists, customer detail, product list, product detail, etc.

If this is a good idea, if the user is moving from one screen to another do you just make the user control visible = false or do you null it out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like you are grouping like functionality so I do not think you have to many. Some of the projects that I have done have had pages with a large amount of resources I converted those to usercontrols and I create each time I show them, otherwise if they are relativly lightweight changing their visibility will work fine. It all boils down to what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: how do you dispose of the previous user control before you create a new one to show the user?

Comment: Yes, but the only reason why was because of memory usage, otherwise changing the visiblity should be fine.

Comment: how do you dispose of it? what container do you recommend?

Comment: I use a panel and just null out the variable that represents the UserControl.